# Python split list elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
lines = [['1 1 4.59114 0.366832 -9.56424 '], ['2 1 5.24742 -0.870574 -8.40649 '], ['3 2 5.21995 -0.38856 -7.39145 ']]
```

I want to split each individual element of the list as follows:

```
[['1', '1 4.59114', '0.366832', '-9.56424'], ['2', '1', '5.24742', '-0.870574', '-8.40649 '], ['3', '2', '5.21995', '-0.38856', '-7.39145']]
```

I tried the following code:

```
m = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    a = re.split(r'\t+', lines[i].rstrip('\t').split(",")
    m.append(a)
```

However split doesn't work on individual list elements. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you getting that list of lists? It seems really odd that you'd have one-element lists with a single string you want to split in each one, without there being a bug somewhere earlier in the code.

Comment: I am getting the list of list from a txt file

Comment: Well, if you're doing the parsing of the file yourself, you probably want to move the line-splitting logic into the parsing code, rather than fixing the data structure up as a separate step afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

You need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the whitespace character and not on the tab `\t`:

```
>>> lines = [['1 1 4.59114 0.366832 -9.56424 '], ['2 1 5.24742 -0.870574 -8.40649 '], ['3 2 5.21995 -0.38856 -7.39145 ']]
>>> [line[0].split() for line in lines]
[['1', '1', '4.59114', '0.366832', '-9.56424'],
 ['2', '1', '5.24742', '-0.870574', '-8.40649'],
 ['3', '2', '5.21995', '-0.38856', '-7.39145']]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a list of list of strings.

```
lines[0][0].split(' ') # lines[0][0] is a string so you can use split
```

will give you ['1', '1', '4.59114', '0.366832', '-9.56424', '']

You can do

```
[x[0].split(' ') for x in lines]
```

to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
print([list[0].split() for list in lines])
```

output :

```
[['1', '1', '4.59114', '0.366832', '-9.56424'], ['2', '1', '5.24742', '-0.870574', '-8.40649'], ['3', '2', '5.21995', '-0.38856', '-7.39145']]
```